# SQL Lite android app Login Authentication from database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a **Login Activity** with **Name** and **password** fields and a **SignUp Activity**, I want to authenticate the **name and password from database**, I have created a **database** and insert values in database using SignUp activity, which was successful, but for **Login Activity** when I click the **login button** my app crashes, I have tried many methods but all in vain.

Login activity

```
  public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    String name;
    String password;
    boolean storedPassword;
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;

    @Bind(R.id.input_name1)
    EditText _nameText;
    @Bind(R.id.input_password)
    EditText _passwordText;
    @Bind(R.id.btn_login)
    Button _loginButton;
    @Bind(R.id.link_signup)
    TextView _signupLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });

        _signupLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the Signup activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
            }
        });
    }

    public void login() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Login");

        if (!validate()) {
            onLoginFailed();
            return;
        }

        _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        progressDialog.show();

        name = _nameText.getText().toString();
        password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        // TODO: Implement your own authentication logic here.
        storedPassword = myDb.getData(name, password);

        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // On complete call either onLoginSuccess or onLoginFailed
                        if (storedPassword = true) {
                            onLoginSuccess();
                        } else {
                            onLoginFailed();
                        }


                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 3000);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SIGNUP) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // TODO: Implement successful signup logic here
                // By default we just finish the Activity and log them in automatically
                this.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Disable going back to the MainActivity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onLoginFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = _nameText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            _nameText.setError("enter a valid name");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _nameText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Database

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "EMAIL";
    public static final String COL_4 = "PASSWORD";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,EMAIL TEXT,PASSWORD INTEGER)");

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertData(String name,String email,String number) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,email);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, number);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    public boolean getData(String name, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE NAME=? AND PASSWORD=?",
                new String[]{name,password});
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
            {
               mCursor.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Log Cat

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 2131
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.DatabaseHelper.getData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:83)
    at com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:47)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: @cricket_007 I have provided the log report at the end

Comment: this is assignment, not comparison `if(storedPassword = true)` you shouyld use compare operator `==` which makes it `if(storedPassword == true)`

Comment: @Yazan It worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to get **Instance** of **DatabaseHelper.class** to use that class.

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(LoginActivity.this);
storedPassword = myDb.getData(name, password);     //like this.
```

Second, you should use like this on your query. **Replace** with this.

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE NAME='?' AND PASSWORD='?';",
            new String[]{name,password});
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 10466
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters. <br> this exception occured

Comment: I did this but I got the exception.

Comment: @BilalAhmed i think you have to remove the single quotes around the ?, i.e: `WHERE NAME=? AND PASSWORD=?` the first part about initializing `myDb` is correct

Comment: @Yazan Can you show me how to retrieve specific columns data from db instead of select * from db.

Comment: @Yazan I am getting another problem.. the login is now successfull. But if I enter wrong values for name and password it does not open the onLoginFailed method.